# Expectation / minimizing variance of weighted sum of means

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value

(I'm assuming the second $\bar x$ should be a $\bar y$), but I'm mostly confused how to solve this problem because it seems like since $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ are values, not random variables, $W$ is just a value?  If that's the case, how can you take the expected value and variance of $W$?  Thanks.

[image: Mathematical Statistics, Chihara & Hesterberg]

(source Mathematical Statistics, Chihara & Hesterberg)

Answer (score 1):

> it seems like since $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ are values, not random variables, $W$ is just a value?  If that's the case, how can you take the expected value and variance of $W$?

If that was the case then you couldn't take the expected value and variance. However the means are defined as
\begin{align}
\bar x &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\\
\bar y &= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i
\end{align}
and because the means are (scaled) sums of random variables they are themselves random variables.

Therefore for part **(a)**, using linearity of expectation,
$$E(W) = aE(\bar x) + (1-a)E(\bar y) = aE\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) +  (1-a)E\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i\right) $$
which can be computed using linearity of expectation again.
\begin{align}
aE\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) +  (1-a)E\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i\right)
&= \frac{a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) + \frac{1-a}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m E(Y_i)\\
&= \frac{a}{n} n\mu + \frac{1-a}{m} m\mu\\
&\\
&= \mu
\end{align}

Similarly for part **(b)**, the variance of $W$ can be computed using the fact that the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of their variances together with $V(kX)=k^2V(X)$.
\begin{align}
V(W)
&= a^2V(\bar x) + (1-a)^2V(\bar y)\\
&= a^2V\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) +  (1-a)^2V\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i\right)\\
&= a^2\sigma_1^2/n + (1-a)^2\sigma_2^2/m
\end{align}
The minimum can be found by differentiating w.r.t. $a$.
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{a}V(W)
&= 2a\sigma_1^2/n - 2(1-a)\sigma_2^2/m\\
&= 2(a(\sigma_1^2/n + \sigma_2^2/m) - \sigma_2^2/m))
\end{align}
Setting this to zero gives
$$a = \frac{\sigma_2^2/m}{\sigma_1^2/n + \sigma_2^2/m} = \frac{n\sigma_2^2}{m\sigma_1^2 + n\sigma_2^2}$$

Comment: That is actually exactly what I got for E[W] and Var(W), but I wasn't confident that what I was doing was allowed because of the nature of x_bar and y_bar.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @user41569 As we have the same answers I have added the derivations rather than just giving hints + the answers.